# Query using if and while loop condition

Tags: r

I have variable name sample

```
post12new12
new12alone12asdas
second12one
thirdone
```

I want query out if sample have one "12" then i =0 and while  sample have more than one '12' then i=i+1

How to do this in r using while and if condition.

```
I have used gregexpr("12",sample)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try

```
library(stringr)
sapply(str_extract_all(v1, "\\d+"), function(x) {
             i1 <- x==12
  if(length(i1)>0) as.integer(sum(i1)>1) else NA})
#[1]  1  1  0 NA
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("post12new12", "new12alone12asdas", "second12one", "thirdone")
```

Comment: or `str_count` should be useful here?

Comment: @Sotos That is better `str_count(v1, "12")` You can post that as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using `str_count` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
ifelse(str_count(v1, '12') == 1, 0, ifelse(str_count(v1, '12') > 1, 1, NA))
#[1]  1  1  0 NA
```